# How do i uninstall Ubuntu Studio 13.04

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-studio

I have an acer aspire one netbook I installed Ubuntu studio because windows xp became unusable and deleted half of the files (I didnt they just disappeared) and now im trying to install windows 7 I have everything but my laptop is not letting me boot from my 64 gig PNY flashdrive it will just resume Ubuntu how do I format my hardrive deleting EVERYTHING?? I have tried commands and everything nothing is working

Comment: You could wipe the hard drive from a [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). But, you may just need to enter the BIOS settings when you first power on your laptop - press F2, F12, or just Enter. Then look for the Boot Device Selection, and select you memory stick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your bios and change your boot order. So that it checks for your flash drive before booting from your had drive.